# Can I use Westvale Abbey in a Commander deck that does not use black?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-commander

Is it possible for me to use [Westvale Abbey](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bWestvale%20Abbey%5d) in a Commander deck that does not use black? I am making a Blue, Green, and White commander deck, and I would like to add Westvale Abbey. Could I use it?

Comment: Related: http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/6292/in-edh-commander-what-is-the-color-identity-of-a-double-faced-card

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you cannot. Westvale Abbey's color identity is Black.

> 903.4. The Commander variant uses color identity to determine what cards can be in a deck with a certain commander. The color identity of a card is the color or colors of any mana symbols in that card’s mana cost or rules text, plus any colors defined by its characteristic-defining abilities (see rule 604.3) or color indicator (see rule 204).
>
> 903.4c The back face of a double-faced card (see rule 711) is included when determining a card’s color identity. This is an exception to rule 711.4a.

And the definition of color indicator:

> 204.1. The color indicator is printed to the left of the type line directly below the illustration. It consists of a circular symbol filled in with one or more colors. A color indicator is usually found on nonland cards without a mana cost.
>
> 204.2. An object with a color indicator is each color denoted by that color indicator.